# Non linear optimization solver in java - replacing the NLP Frontline Solver

Tags: nlp, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I am using Java to solve a non-linear optimization - skew for option-pricing.

The code calls the java api for FrontLine Solver,
with Problem_type.OptNLP
and Solver_Type.minimize
and the Evolutionary engine.
And a java callback is used to calculate objective&constraints
BUT THERE is no callback for derivatives or hessian (i think)

I am not a maths expert, but this seems a non-linear minimization of a non-smooth (?) multi-dimentional function ?!

Can anyone suggest a alternative libray which can be used ?
I am running onlinux/java but we can call any dll/backend if required
Also - i am not sure if an evolutionary/genetic engine is really needed. Maybe it was just selected and it worked.

Comment: There is not much to go on here. May be best is to talk to the author of this code.

Comment: So i am now using NLopt (in C) with  ESCH (evolutionary algorithm) to solve the global optimization.  

Any pure Java alternative ?